# What datatype should I use for my column? [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a content management system at work. I will have a column to hold the body of our users' content (HTML) and I'm not too sure what column type to use. I don't want to arbitrarily assign a maximum length but I don't know if using a LONGTEXT or BLOB field is overkill.

Maybe someone could give me a tip or point me in the direction of some sort of "best practices" article for these types of things? :)

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should GZip and Base64 encode the HTML then store it in a Text column.

Comment: What advantage am I gaining from GZip? Would I do it for the compression or is there some other advantage that I am missing.

Comment: I would say the compression is a HUGE advantage. You can cut your DB to web server transfer times in half (maybe exaggerated but there is a speed increase). Plus over time you will require a lot less storage space for the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-type-overview.html so you know the size constraints of each field. Afterwards you can choose based off your understanding of the application if you should allow more.

**Text**
A TEXT column with a maximum length of 65,535 (216 – 1) characters

**Medium Text**
A TEXT column with a maximum length of 16,777,215 (224 – 1) characters.

**Long Text**
A TEXT column with a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 or 4GB (232 – 1) characters.

I think you should set some kind of limit. It might be worth looking into what other software does (like Word Press) for example.

As for ChaosPandion: GZip is binary, if you're going to do that he should be using BLOB instead.

Comment: Also remember that the Text column (like the varchar column) has a variable length. Meaning that it only uses up the amount of space that is contained inside the field (unlike CHAR). The only space it uses is a 2 byte prefix so that the database knows the total size of the field.

Answer (score 0):

Use LONGTEXT so you can search it.

Comment: If searching is a requirement, this would be the best option.

Comment: Who is going to be searching through a nasty chunk of HTML?

Comment: Since when does MySQL require the field to be LONGTEXT to search?