# how to store html code in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store some html codes in mysql database , I did not  do this ever before , what is the correct way to store html in db?

```
$html_code='<div class="hello"><p>hello world</p></div>';

// database table
part_name | html_code
hello | ??
```

Comment: `part_name | html_code
hello | ??` What is this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store HTML into MySQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641561/store-html-into-mysql-database)

Comment: And have you ever stored `anything` in a MySQL database before?

Comment: *Exact duplicate:* [What datatype should I use for my column? \[MySQL\]](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1805199)

Comment: but I want to do some encode or decode in my php .mysql_real_escape_string function output error when I code in my php

Comment: @linjuming What was the error? We will need to see the code you've got already.

Comment: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in D:\phpnow\htdocs\laji\laji.php on line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommend is use [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) to do it for you , sanitize input and remove all malicious code

otherwise you have to write a function like `remove_special_chars($string)` for removing special chars like `<` `>` `"` and replacing them with something like `&lt;`,`&gt;`,`&quot;`... and save to your db.
And after reading data from db use a function like `add_special_chars($string)` for vice versa action to show the content. which are not easy and still non reliable

Comment: Why removing tags before db insertion? html should be inserted as is, and only "sanitized" before outputting. There's no malicious html/js inside a db

Comment: @DamienPirsy for example if `<script> alert('something') </script>` stores in a comment field by user, when we try to read it what happend?

Comment: And that's why I said sanitize BEFORE OUTPUTTING. `<script>whatever</script>`, when INSIDE A DB CELL, what happens?

Comment: @DamienPirsy, I edited my response, please recheck and edit my answer to true reply, Thank you